# Phone number parsing and validation

Tags: java, android, string, android-contacts

I have a phone number that can appear in different formats. I need to match that number with a model number.

Incoming call is the number from which the call is coming and the other numbers are the formats in which the numbers are saved in our phone table.

So how can I split the string so that I could get/verify meaningful output?

```
   public class Trial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String incomingcall,number1,number2,number3,newincoming,new1 = null;
        incomingcall="+919045308261";
        number1="9045308261";
        number2="09045308261";
        number3= "+91 90 45 308261";

        //int i= incomingcall.length();
        newincoming=incomingcall.replace("+91", "000");
        System.out.println(newincoming);
        if(number1.length()<=10){
        new1 =  ("000"+number1);
            System.out.println(new1);
        }

        if(newincoming.equals(new1)){
            System.out.println("Numbers matched");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Here is a phone number parser/validator put out by Google https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: regex is useful doing things like this. Give it a try, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: ok i give a look on both these links and thanks for you help

Comment: I used the one Frank Tudor suggested in many apps before, I would strongly recommend it. It's a complete API that lets you do anything you want regarding phone numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it an official answer shall we?

Here is a phone number parser/validator put out by Google [code.google.com/p/libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)